# Sending SPDY requests results in "The request timed out" errors with NSUrlSession in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nginx, nsurlsession

My iOS app loads images from an nginx HTTP server. After I send 400+ such requests the networking 'gets stuck' and all subsequent HTTP requests result in "The request timed out" error. I can make the images load again only when I restart the app.

**Details:**

1. I am using `NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL` to send four hundred HTTP GET requests to jpeg files.
2. Requests are sent sequentially, one after another. The interval between requests is 10 ms.
3. Each previous unfinished request is cancelled with `cancel()` method of `NSURLSessionDataTask` object.

**Interestingly:**

1. I can only have this issue with HTTPS requests and when SPDY is enabled on the server.
2. Non-secure HTTP requests work fine.
3. Non-SPDY HTTPS requests work fine. I tested it by turning SPDY off on the server side, in the nginx config.
4. Problem appears both on iOS 8 and 9, on physical device and in the simulator. Both on Wi-Fi and LTE.
5. When I look at nginx access logs, I can still see the 'stuck' requests coming in. Important nuance: the request log record appears at the exact moment when the iOS app is giving up on it after the time out period ends.
6. I was hoping to analyze HTTP requests with [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com) but the problem cures itself when requests go through Charles. That is - everything works with Charles, much like effect in quantum mechanics when the fact of looking influences the outcome.
7. I was able to reproduce the issue when the iOS app connected to two different servers with vastly different nginx configurations. This probably means that the issue is not related to a particular nginx setup.
8. I analyzed the app using "Activity Monitor" instrument. The number of threads it is using during the bulk HTTP requests jumps from 5 to 10. In comparison, when I send just a single HTTP requests the number of threads jumps to 8. CPU load rarely goes above 30%.

What can be the cause of the issue? Can anyone recommend other ways or tools for analysing and debugging it?

#### Analysing with scheduling instrument

[image]

#### Demo app

This demo app reproduces the issue 100% of the time for me.

https://github.com/exchangegroup/ImageLoadDemo

#### Versions and settings

My nginx config: http://pastebin.com/pYYjdxfP

**OS X**: 10.10.4 (14E46), **iOS**: 8 and 9, **Xcode**: 7.0 (7A218), **nginx**: 1.9.4

#### Not ideal workaround

I managed to keep requests working only if I create a new NSURLSession for each individual request and clear the previous session with `finishTasksAndInvalidate` or `invalidateAndCancel`.

```
// Request 1

let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()     
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration)
session.dataTaskWithURL ...

// Request 2

// clear the previous request
session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
let session2 = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration)
session2.dataTaskWithURL ...
```

Comment: What nginx do with these requests? Show config

Comment: @AlexeyTen, here is the nginx config: http://pastebin.com/pYYjdxfP

Comment: How many threads are running on the client when this happens?

Comment: @quellish just one thread. iOS app sends requests sequentially, one after another with interval of 10 ms.

Comment: If you can reproduce it, do so and halt the app in the debugger - see how many threads are running. It's likely all these requests are piling up waiting for a resource to be freed before they can continue - network latency, system resources like threads, etc. This may also explain why it does not reproduce when you are using Charles.

Comment: @quellish I analyzed the app using "Activity Monitor" instrument. The number of threads it is using during the bulk HTTP requests jumps from 5 to 10. In comparison, when I send just a single HTTP requests the number of threads jumps to 8. CPU load rarely goes above 30%

Comment: The Activity Monitor application will not tell you what you need to see, but the Instruments application or Xcode (lldb) can.

Comment: @quellish, I did use the Instruments application in Xcode for that, it has an instrument called "Activity monitor".

Comment: Try the scheduling instrument instead - or use the debugger. Again, Activity Monitor will not tell you anything useful to your issue as you have described it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89749/discussion-between-evgenii-and-quellish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that iOS started sending the request, and then packet loss prevented the headers and request body from being fully delivered.

Another possibility that comes to mind is that your server may not be logging the request until it actually finishes trying to deliver it, which would make the time stamps in the server logs line up with when the connection was closed, rather than when it was opened.  (IIRC, that's what Apache does; I haven't worked with nginx, so I can't speak for its behavior.)  If that's the case, then this is just a simple connection stall.  As for why it is stalling, I couldn't guess.

Does the problem occur exclusively for HTTPS traffic?  If you can reproduce it with HTTP, you don't need Charles Proxy; just use OS X's "Internet Sharing" feature, and capture the packets with tcpdump or wireshark, listening on the bridge interface.  If you can't reproduce it with HTTP, my money would be on a problem with fetching the CRLs or performing the OCSP check while validating the server's certificate.

Is your app ending up with a huge number of threads as a result of excessive async dispatching to new queues, by any chance?  Because that could easily cause all sorts of odd misbehavior.

How long is the timeout?  If it is too short, your app might simply be running up against performance limitations of the hardware while processing the results of 400 requests delivered in only four seconds.

Also, are you trying to schedule these requests simultaneously?  Because I seem to recall reading about a bug that causes NSURLSession to hit a brick wall if you start too many tasks in a single session at the same time.  You might try adding tasks only after the number of tasks in a session drops below some threshold and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: thank you for your help. iOS app sends requests sequentially, one after another with interval of 10 ms. The previous request is cancelled if it's in "Running" state.

Comment: I will try to reproduce the problem without HTTPs, good point.

Comment: Whew.  That's a seriously short timeout.  It is possible that you're exceeding the rate at which the session can clean itself up.  Have you tried it with NSURLConnection, and if so, does it fail in the same way?  (Not that I'd advise using a deprecated API typically, but it would be interesting to know whether they behave differently in this regard.)

Comment: Yes true, this is a very short interval, I deliberately made it so short so I can reproduce it reliably in a demo app, so Apple can debug it. In my real app the interval between requests is never shorter than 100ms, but even with this bigger time interval I get the same issue.

Comment: I will check NSURLConnection as you suggested, thanks.

Comment: It does work with HTTP. And it even works with HTTPS when SPDY is turned off on the server side.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a SPDY bug, either in iOS or nginx, then.  Definitely file a bug and attach that test tool.  I'm sure the CFNetwork team would love to take a look at it.