# Can I turn SPDY off in an iOS app that uses NSURLSession?

Tags: ios, nginx, nsurlsession, spdy

My iOS app is having networking issues when it loads images from an HTTPS nginx web server with SPDY enabled. The issue is described here: [Sending SPDY requests results in "The request timed out" errors with NSUrlSession in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32493339/sending-400-https-spdy-requests-result-in-the-request-timed-out-errors-with-n)

I am using NSURLSession for my networking.  I did experiments and confirmed that my problem is fixed if I turn SPDY off on the server side. Unfortunately I can not turn SPDY off on production nginx server because I have no control over it. Can I turn SPDY off in the iOS app instead?

OS X: 10.10.4 (14E46), iOS: 8 and 9, Xcode: 7.0 (7A218), nginx: 1.9.4

Answer (score 1):

You *might* be able to pre-populate the Upgrade header field in your NSURLRequest with something that nginx will handle as a non-SPDY, non-HTTP/2 request, e.g.

Upgrade: TLS/1.2

but the URL loading system might just stomp on it, in which case the only way to disable it would by configuring the server to compare the user agent string (or any other header that you provide) and refusing to upgrade the connection.